# Query data from VIEWS in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to query data from VIEWS in db2 but my query is not correct.

```
SELECT TRIM(NAME),TRIM(ADDRESS) 
  from SYSCAT.VIEWS 
  where TYPE = 'V'
  and TABSCHEMA = 'work.SCHEMA'
  and tabname IN ('EMPLOYEE');
```

Schema>VIEWS>EMPLOYEE

The above query returns nothing but data is in Employee

Comment: And why aren't you satisfied with this query ?

Comment: do you have a view you can query with `select * from "work.SCHEMA".employee` ?

Comment: @nfgl I have a table for employee but there's different versions of that table but views has the latest version. So I need to query from Views but the above query returns nothing even though there is data

Comment: This query doesn't run, it can't, none of the column name exists in SYSCAT.VIEWS. It's like you expect the list of views in the db to return info about employees. Please explain more what you want to do

Comment: @nfgl I want to retrieve all the data for name and address column in schema>views>employee

Comment: Catalog tables in the SYSCAT schema contain meta information about DB objects.  SYSCAT.VIEWS shows information about the views defined in your DB.  Not the actual data in the view.

Comment: do you know what the name of the view and the schema where it is. If not please explain your DB what you bean by table versions and how they are related to views, maybe with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.First Schema in query
```

query:'create schema schema_name'

example:'create schema  tbl'

```
2.create a view in query
```

query:'create view view_name
as
select*from  table_name'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just click a link to learn schema and view

[Go  to learn a view in Sql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)

[Go to learn in schema in Sql](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-schema-in-sql-server/)